# Filter JSON Data with multiple filters in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Ok, i cannot make this work so i'm turning to you, i've been hacking away at this all morning and i give up. I have some checkboxes which create an array of filters like this:

```
var filters = [Diesel,CarWash]
```

I'm trying to filter a JSON file to find a match that contains all (not any) the items in that filter set. So, for the array above, i'd like to filter the JSON file (sample below) to find a location with both Diesel AND CarWash. That would return only the last item, which has both. I'm using jquery for this project and I think that $filter will work but it is beyond my ken.

```
[
  {
    "FacilityID": 123,
    "Diesel": 0,
    "ATM": 0,
    "CarWash": "None"
  },
{
    "FacilityID": 456,
    "Diesel": 1,
    "ATM": 0,
    "CarWash": "None"
  },
{
    "FacilityID": 789,
    "Diesel": 1,
    "ATM": 0,
    "CarWash": "Full"
  }
]
```

Comment: What criteria you're filtering by? I guess for `CarWash` it must have a value of `"Full"`, and for `Diesel` it needs to have a value of `0`. For filters to work, you will need to return a boolean if a certain item matches the criteria: so you will need to convert the requirements you have in mind into a boolean check of sorts.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. They are different (not all zeros and ones).

Comment: And where do you get that information from? Since `filters` is an array that does not contain any metadata, how are you going to filter by, say, `FacilityID`? I.e. the properties you want to filter by contains no additional information on *how* to filter.

Comment: Ok what if the filter array looked like this, generated from a series of chekboxes:

`var filters = [{Diesel: "1", CarWash: "Full"}]`

Comment: @Igiffin, Ive updated my answer below to incorporate `var filters = {Diesel: "1", CarWash: "Full"}` (note I did remove the array wrapper and just used the object itself., if you really need to match multiply objects with filters, please let me know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```js
var filters = {Diesel: "1", CarWash: "Full"};


    var facilities = [{
        "FacilityID": 123,
        "Diesel": 0,
        "ATM": 0,
        "CarWash": "None"
      },
      {
        "FacilityID": 456,
        "Diesel": 1,
        "ATM": 0,
        "CarWash": "None"
      },
      {
        "FacilityID": 789,
        "Diesel": 1,
        "ATM": 0,
        "CarWash": "Full"
      }
    ];


    var selectedFacility = null;

    // loop over each facilities
    $.each(facilities, function(i, facility) {
      var matchesAllFilters = true;
      // loop over each filter
      $.each(filters, function(filterName, filterValue) {
        var facilityValue = facility[filterName];
        
        if (filterValue != facilityValue) {
            matchesAllFilters = false;
          return false;
        }
      });
      if (matchesAllFilters) {
        selectedFacility = facility;
      }
    });

    console.log(selectedFacility );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try out this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = [
    {
      "FacilityID": 123,
      "Diesel": 0,
      "ATM": 0,
      "CarWash": "None"
    },
    {
        "FacilityID": 456,
        "Diesel": 1,
        "ATM": 0,
        "CarWash": "None"
      },
    {
        "FacilityID": 789,
        "Diesel": 1,
        "ATM": 0,
        "CarWash": "Full"
      }
    ]

    returned_value = retun_value(data)
    alert(returned_value)
});

function retun_value(data){
    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++ ){
       if(data[i].Diesel && data[i].CarWash && data[i].CarWash !='None'){
         return i
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, this wont handle dynamic filters values. OP doesnt specify this, but it seems very likely given the code